# unused argument of VlnPlot

Tags: r, seurat

I want to use `VlnPlot` to draw the figure.

```
VlnPlot(hc_mild_severe_integrated, features.plot = c("CXCL2", "IL1A"), group.by = "tech")
```

> Error in VlnPlot(hc_mild_severe_integrated, features.plot = c("CXCL2",  :
> unused argument (features.plot = c("CXCL2", "IL1A"))

Comment: Argument is "features" not "features.plot".

Comment: Use `features` inplace of `features.plot`. Visit [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hello zx8754 and Bappa Das, Thank you so much for your great help! Use features inplace of features.plot. Best,  Yue